# Is there a quick and easy way to reverse a dummy variable?

Tags: r

I currently have a dummy variable titled 'white', where it is given a value of 1 if white and 0 if non-white.
Is there a way to add another variable that actually specifies the result as 'white' or 'non-white' rather than 1 and 0?

I tried to simply using the ifelse function but it can only be used for binary results, is there a function that can be used to switch variables to characters?

Comment: `ifelse(white == 1, "white", "non-white")`? Or `factor(white, levels = 0:1, labels = c("non-white", "white"))`.